# How can I add the additional information below file icons in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

DropBox has started adding status text underneath files and folders in the Finder and I was wondering if anyone knows how this is done?  Searching the web has proven fruitless (unless I'm just searching for the wrong things.  Any ideas?  Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

(Apparently first time askers can't attach images here.  Here's a shared link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1020197/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-29%20at%2010.32.23%20AM.png)

How would I add the "Up to date" type label to my saved files?

For further clarification, I'm looking to have files created by my own app show the additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into something else I believe I found the answer to my question and it isn't applicable to what I was trying to do.  It appears to be available in extensions related to synchronization services for folders and their contents.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH15-SW1

"Add, remove, and update badges and labels on items in a monitored folder."

Thanks to those who offered input!